# Is there a way to use class/enum with namespace when namespace has an another class that has same name with the namespace?

Tags: swift

First of all, I know, the title of the question is little awkward.

I have an enum in my application named `UserState`

```swift
enum UserState {
  ...
}
```

I'm trying to use `AWSMobileClient` library in my application but it has also another enum named `UserState` and I'm trying to use with namespaced way.

```swift
import AWSMobileClient
...
var foo: AWSMobileClient.UserState?
```

But I'm getting an error because there is a class named `AWSMobileClient` in the `AWSMobileClient` namespace.
[image: error details]

I can prefer to import just the enum instead of all namespace but I also need `AWSMobileClient` class in the same file.

I also find a dirty solution to use `UserState` like defining a typealias in a different file.

*In A.swift*

```swift
import enum AWSMobileClient.UserState

typealias AWSUserState = AWSMobileClient.UserState
```

*In B.swift*

```swift
import AWSMobileClient
...
var foo: AWSUserState? // this works
```

But there should be a better solution for this problem.

Comment: Renaming **your** enum is not an option?

Comment: It's absolutely an option but I'm new on swift and I'm trying to find the right solution. This should be a problem that have been already solved I thought.